# Error para ejecutar comando Docker

Tags: javascript, nodejs, docker

Hola amigos disculpa tengo una duda. Tengo mi siguiente archivo de dockerFile y este es el codigo que corro para hacer funcionar docker.

```
docker build -t XDServer .
```

y este es el file

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /index

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .


CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

y mi carpeta es la siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y pues digamos que mi archivo que maneja el servidor es el index.js
pero no logro hacer que funcione ya que me sale el siguiente error.

```
invalid argument "XDServer" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
See 'docker build --help'.
```

Comment: El error estaba en que no se puede ejecutar el nombre con mayusculas.

Answer (score 0):

La razón del error es que cuando se corre el comando `docker build -t XDServer`
para solucionar esto se debe ejecutar en minusculas `docker build -t xdserver`